# ¿Cómo añadir espacios en blanco mediante CSS?

Tags: html, css

¿Cómo podemos añadir espacios en blanco mediante CSS, se puede?

**Se puede añadir un espacio en blanco**, y otro contenido mediante CSS, por ejemplo, para lograr lo siguiente:

```
Home / Skills / Listening
```

Se puede usar el siguiente CSS:

```
.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.breadcrumb li::after {
    content: " / ";
}
.breadcrumb li:last-child::after {
    content: "";
}
.breadcrumb {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Y HTML:

```
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Skills</li>
    <li>Listening</li>
</ul>
```

*Se incluye un espacio en blanco a cada lado de la barra inclinada*. **¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezca en lugar de un solo espacio en blanco 2 o más?**

No se puede usar el espacio de HTML, es decir `&nbsp;` ya que daría por ejemplo el siguiente resultado:

```
Home &nbsp;/&nbsp; Skills &nbsp;/&nbsp; Listening
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se por qué quieres poner varios espacios en blanco, sería mejor usar márgenes o rellenos para separar los elementos pero si por lo que sea tienen que ser espacios puedes usar el código unicode para el espacio (`\0000a0`) en la propiedad `content`:

```css
.breadcrumb li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.breadcrumb li::after {
    content: "\0000a0 \0000a0 \0000a0 \0000a0 / ";
}
.breadcrumb li:last-child::after {
    content: "";
}
.breadcrumb {
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Skills</li>
    <li>Listening</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

**OPCIÓN 1 `PADDING`**

- Puedes valerte de la propiedad `padding` que permite generar un espacio al rededor de un elemento.
- En este caso vamos a trabajar sobre el elemento que tiene la clase `.breadcrumb li::after`

De este modo

```
.breadcrumb li::after {
    content: " / ";
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

- De modo que le estamos indicando con el `0px` que arriba y abajo tendrá de *padding* 0 pixeles, esto para no alterar tu maquetación
- Le daremos un `padding` de 20 px como segundo valor a la propiedad para indicarle que ahora esos valores afectaran tanto a la izquierda como a la derecha; quedando para esos lados una medida idéntica

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title></title>
      <style>
        .breadcrumb li {
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
        }
        .breadcrumb li::after {
            content: " / ";
            padding: 0px 20px;
        }
        .breadcrumb li:last-child::after {
            content: "";
        }
        .breadcrumb {
            list-style: none;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Listening</li>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**OPCIÓN 1 `WORD-SPACING`**

O bien puedes ocupar la propiedad `word-spacing` de este modo

```
.breadcrumb {
            list-style: none;
          word-spacing: 30px;
        }
```

Esta propiedad esblece la longitud de espacios entre palabras y etiquetas

- Referencia de [word-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-spacing)
- Referencia de [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding)